# auto share links using php curl

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want to auto share links in my facebook wall using this script :

```
   $attachment =  array(
    'email' => 'mail',
    'password' => 'password',
    'access_token' => 'my token',
    'message' => "my message",
    'name' => 'name',
    'link' => 'my_url',
    'description' => "my description"
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/links');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0;    en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $json = json_decode($result);
    $post_id = $json->{'id'};
    curl_close($ch);
```

at the began it worked for me but after trying it for 7 times or more  i got this error :

```
{ "error": { "message": "(#100) The parameter url is required", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100 } }
```

how can I fix it

Answer (score 1):

**links**

*Create*

You can **post a link** on the user's behalf by issuing an HTTP POST request to **PROFILE_ID/feed** with the `publish_stream` permissions.

The other fields are taken from the metadata of the page URL given in the 'link' param.

If the create is successful, you get the following return.

Refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#links

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed');
```